# How can I use the text from a file like variables

Tags: c++, file

I am making a little ATM-Bank system.

I'm asking how can I take the values from a text file (database) and use it into some variables.

I already can store: `name`, `age`, `money`, `card number` and `pin` into the text file, but I have troubles when I try to verify the name and the pin from the .txt file.

Here is the code. This program has 2 versions: English and Romanian. I made just the "ro" part("en" part just introduction), it's just the read/write into file section:

```
void ro_utilizator_nou()
{

    system ("cls");

    string nume;
    int ziuac, lunac, anc, ziuan, lunan, ann, varsta, anbisect, bani=0;

    time_t t = time(NULL);
    tm* timePtr = localtime(&t);

    ziuac=timePtr->tm_mday;
    lunac=timePtr->tm_mon+1;
    anc=timePtr->tm_year+1900;

nume_gresit:
    cout<<"Introduceti numele: "<<endl;
    cin>>nume;
    cin.sync();
    if (!string_litere(nume)){system("cls");goto nume_gresit;}

data_gresita:
    cout<<"Va rugam sa va introduceti data nasterii."<<endl;

    cout<<"Introduceti ziua nasterii:"<<endl;
    cin>>ziuan; cin.clear(); cin.ignore();
    if (ziuan<1 || ziuan>31) {system("cls"); goto data_gresita;}

    cout<<"Introduceti luna nasterii:"<<endl;
    cin>>lunan; cin.clear(); cin.ignore();
    if (lunan<1 || lunan>12) {system("cls"); goto data_gresita;}

    cout<<"Introduceti anul nasterii:"<<endl;
    cin>>ann; cin.clear(); cin.ignore();
    if (ann>2018 || ann<1900) {system("cls"); goto data_gresita;}

    if ((ann % 4 == 0 && ann % 100 != 0 ) || ann % 400 == 0) anbisect = 1; else anbisect = 0; //stabilirea daca anul nasterii este bisect sau nu
    if (ziuan<1 || (lunan==2 && anbisect==1 && ziuan>29) || (lunan==2 && anbisect==0 && ziuan>28) || ((lunan==1 || lunan==3 || lunan==5 || lunan==7 || lunan==8 || lunan==10 || lunan==12) && ziuan>31) || ((lunan==4 || lunan==6 || lunan==9 || lunan==11) && ziuan>30) )
    {system("cls"); cout<<"Data nasterii incorecta!"<<endl<<endl;; goto data_gresita;}

    varsta=anc-ann; //stabilirea varstei
    if (lunan>lunac) varsta--;
    else if (lunan==lunac) if (ziuan>ziuac) varsta--;

    cout<<endl<<"Aveti "<<varsta<<" ani."<<endl;

    if (varsta<14) {
        cout<<"Ne pare rau, nu puteti avea un card de credit daca nu aveti minim 14 ani impliniti."<<endl<<endl;
        system("pause");
        main();
    }

    int card_number = generare_card_number();
    int card_pin = generare_pin();
    cout<<"Numarul cardului (si al contului) dumneavoastra este: "<<card_number<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"ATENTIE! Urmeaza sa va afisam codul secret PIN!!!"<<endl<<"(Apasati orice tasta)"<<endl;
    cin.ignore(); cout<<"Pinul dumneavoastra este: "<<card_pin<<endl;cin.ignore();

    ofstream new_data_base("database.txt", ios::app);
    new_data_base << nume << ' ' << varsta << ' ' << bani << ' ' << card_number << ' ' << card_pin <<endl;
    new_data_base.close();
}
void ro_utilizator_existent()
{

    ifstream data_base("database.txt");

    string nume, nume2;
    int pin, optiune, inregistrat, varsta, bani, card_number, card_pin;

    if (!data_base.eof()){
        data_base >> nume >> varsta >> bani >> card_number >> card_pin;
    }

nume_gresit:
    system ("cls");
    cout<<"Introduceti numele: "<<endl;
    cin>>nume2;
    cin.sync();
    if (!string_litere(nume2)){system("cls");goto nume_gresit;}

    while (data_base >> nume){

        if (nume == nume2) goto pin_gresit;

        else {

            system("cls");
            cout<<"Nume gresit! Nu sunteti inregistrat?"<<endl;

repetare:
            cout<<"1 - Sunt inregistrat"<<endl<<"2 - Nu sunt inregistrat"<<endl;
            cin>>inregistrat; cin.clear(); cin.ignore();

            if (inregistrat==1) goto nume_gresit;
            else if (inregistrat==2) ro_utilizator_nou();
            else {system("cls"); goto repetare;
            }
        }
    }


pin_gresit:
    cout<<"Introduceti PIN-ul:"<<endl;
    cin>>pin; cin.clear(); cin.ignore();

    while (data_base >> nume >> varsta >> bani >> card_number >> card_pin){
        if (pin == card_pin) goto reusit;
        else {system("cls"); cout<<"PIN gresit!"; goto pin_gresit;}
    }

reusit:
    system("cls");

    cout<<"Logare reusita!"<<endl<<endl;

optiune_gresita:
    cout<<"1. Informatii cont."<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Cautare utilizator."<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Adaugare fonduri."<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Transfer bancar."<<endl;
    cout<<"5. Retragere numerar."<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"9. Delogare."<<endl<<endl;

    cin>>optiune;
}
```

When i input a suitable name it's saying that the name is wrong; or when the name works, any number is considered like the right pin.

p.s.: with time i calculated the age("varsta");
p.s.2: "bani" means money
p.s.3: I took some examples from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3m3qLNX9zA , but it's different; my code (whole) is here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/zmujjs9014mej7c/BCR_ATM.cpp/file

Comment: This is really bad code. For starters your use of `goto` is very much frowned upon. As is your use of [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Numbers) and placing multiple statements on a single line or the inconsistent indentation.

Comment: And please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I know..but I need to solve this..If I enter a good name, something the program will say that it's wrong; and when it works, if I put any pin in there it will work.....

Comment: Sorry, I really tried but I've barely reached the place when most probably (but I'm not sure) the logic you're referring to in the post is located. It's really hard, and non-English variable names do not help. Maybe if I could easily copy&paste and run the program, I could see the problem for myself, but I can't because it's not a [mcve].

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger allows you to single-step through your code, *watching* the values in variables.  Often, debugging is faster than correctly posting to StackOverflow and *waiting* for somebody to inspect or debug your program for you.

Comment: Why do you use `cin.sync()`?  Do you know how it functions?  Is it necessary?

Comment: Where is the function definition for `string_litere`?  What is the functionality?  What does it return?  Does it modify its parameter?

Comment: Do you *need* to clear the screen?  There may be some useful information that was previously entered, that will disappear when the screen is cleared.  Also, the "cls" command is not standard across operating systems (such as Linux).

Comment: Research the `bool` type.  Using `1` and `0` for Boolean values is so ancient (like in the 1960's).  Prefer to use `bool` variables and `true` and `false` instead of `1` and `0`.

Comment: Where is `generare_card_number()` function defined?  Does it generate a random credit card number?  Are leading zeros significant (storing as integer removes leading zeros)?  Can it be negative? (The `int` type allows for negative numbers.)

Comment: I'm stopping the code inspection, too many questions to ask.  Reformat your code.  Use *structured programming techniques*.  Use a debugger and don't clear the screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you write the file each person is on a line:

```
new_data_base << nume << ' ' << varsta << ' ' << bani << ' ' << card_number << ' ' << card_pin <<endl;
```

So when you read the file. Always read one whole record at a time. That way you don't have to worry about partial reads or finding the start of the next record.

So replace:

```
while (data_base >> nume){
```

with

```
while ( data_base >> nume >> varsta >> bani >> card_number >> card_pin ) {
```

Then you can remove the parts where you try and ignore or extract different parts of the object.

My next piece of advice is important.

1. Get this working/
2. Go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com
   Note they only look at working code, so do step one first.
3. Get a review. This is exceedingly important.

You are using so many bad habits. You need to stop now. You need some real advice on how to write code. If you continue down this road you will just get into a really bad shape that the code is unsalvageable.

Stop using MediaFire to host your source. Nobody is going to download that. Git yourself a [github account](https://github.com/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is just my first C++ "big" project so I care only about the functionabily of the program, not the code at all. I have time to change the way I'm writing the code(I'm 16 yo). But I still have a problem: any number I inpit, it says that it's a good one(even if it's not in the databas.txt file or it's 1/2/3 digit long. I can't fix this, I think I wrote the whole function correctly.